# HTML does not recognize CSS file - Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I recently started working on my first python + django project and I'm working on some visual things, but I noticed that the HTML isn't recognizing my CSS file.

I follow the documentation about How to manage static files but nothing worked.

So, this is my settings.py

```
#app definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #personalizacao
    #'grappelli',
    #Configuraçoes principais
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]
```

```
#statics configs
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',    #causes verbose duplicate notifications in django 1.9
)
```

In my HTML I have

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
```

And I can call the stuff that I have on the static/img folder with no problem

So does anyone know what can it be? I don't know where to look anymore

This is the structure of my django project
[image]

Comment: can you share the structure of you django project ? and show the exact place of the "styles.css" file ?

Comment: Hey 0urz4g, I just edited the post with an image of the structure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to remove everything and keep only :

```py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

If it still doesn't work, try to move styles.css inside an app folder, like "produtos" : produtos/static/css/styles.css

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you